# Discord.py Command is not acessed in pylance (Musicbot)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I tried making a  simple music bot with python but for some reason all my commands like resume, pause, play, disconnect are not acessed in pylance does anyone know a fix? When i try to type it in discord it says "Command "join" is not found.

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


        @commands.command()
        async def join (self,ctx):
            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            if ctx.voice_client is None:
                await voice_channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        
        
        @commands.command()
        async def disconnect (self,ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

        @commands.command()   
        async def play(self,ctx,url):
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 - reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'} 
            YDL_OPTIONS = {'format' : "bestaudio"}
            vc = ctx.voice_client

            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
                url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
                source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                vc.play(source)

        @commands.command()
        async def pause (self,ctx): 
            await ctx.voice_client.pause()
            await ctx.send ("Paused ⏸")

        @commands.command()
        async def resume (self,ctx): 
            await ctx.voice_client.resume()
            await ctx.send ("Resumed ⏯")       

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same exact issue. Your commands are indented into the scope of __init__(). Easy to miss because it still compiles.